# Moving from Active Record to Domain Object pattern approach

Tags: c#, activerecord, domain-driven-design

Here's the scenario:

I've joined a team who are starting to develop a fairly large financial system and are supposedly aiming towards DDD, with a rich behavioral domain model.  However, I can see many smells in the current area of the project which point to Active Record: A single "Save" method in an application service; a fairly anemic set of domain objects which have a big "Validate" method etc.  All very CRUD-like and is becoming increasingly difficult to manage.

The user story I'm developing roughly translates to "When a Direct Debit has transitioned from particular state to another (not budgeted to budgeted), create a task item for an advisor to work on". There are various rules which determine what "not budgeted" and "budgeted" mean.

Currently the DirectDebit class doesn't have a concept of "state" at all, it is a fairly large DTO (with several child objects - again, all DTOs) with around a 1000 lines of validation logic to attempt to determine what shape it should be in.  The business have "clear" concepts of the different states that a Direct Debit can be in, and I do believe the domain is rich enough to warrant a Domain model.

The DirectDebit Application service has a "Save" method which passes in the updated Direct Debit (from the UI). The method gets the existing DirectDebit from the repository, totally ignores it, runs the "Validate" on the updated Direct Debit object, and saves it to the repo. The method then audits the changes between the old and the new Direct Debit objects.

I'm trying to break away from the CRUD-like monster that's starting to develop here and demonstrate to the team how they can start to refactor this.

Ideally, I would like to start to refactor the domain object to use a State pattern, use good encapsulation and perhaps use Domain Events to bubble up the fact the state has changed.  The Application layer would have a Domain Event handler called "CreateTaskWhenBudgeted" or something like that to decouple the logic.

My issue is the large "Save" Direct Debit method, which originates from the UI.

Are there any strategies for breaking up / refactoring such a method? There's no easy way to tell what's "changed", as there isn't a clear command that's happening.  Or, should I just keep adding to the mess and ignore what I believe to be an issue....?

Here's a cut down version of the Application Service:

```
public void SaveDirectDebit(DirectDebit directDebit)
{
    directDebit.Validate(false);

    var beforeDirectDebit = _directDebitRepository.FetchDirectDebit(directDebit.ExpenditureId.Id);

    _directDebitRepository.SaveDirectDebit(directDebit);

    var afterDirectDebit = _directDebitRepository.FetchDirectDebit(directDebit.ExpenditureId.Id);

    var accountAuditLog = CreateDirectDebitAudit(beforeDirectDebit, afterDirectDebit);

    _auditLogRepository.CreateAudit(accountAuditLog);
}
```

Comment: As you are developing a new User Story and you know the trigger, why do you just not expose a different method ? In the first time you will maybe duplicate code...

Comment: That's a fair point - I could expose a second method, but I would potentially be saving to the database twice.  I was hoping there would be a way to refactor from the inside out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is of course no one way to do it (the good way vs the others), you have multiple parameters (time, complexity...).

**The inside out way**

Disclaimer : the more the legacy code is huge, the more this approach seems to be hard to implement (Condition of success for me : you should not be the only one who care about this refactoring).

-> Save to database is a technical stuff. You have to first introduce some Ubiquitous language to make the implicit explicit and to be able to introduce concepts and do design (create boundaries and separate contexts).

**The other way**

The other way it is what I started to describe in my comment, for me it's related to what Eric Evans calls "bubble context" when you are surrounded by a legacy system, it's easier to start with a clean small bounded context. This isolation will help you to apply a better (different) design than in the existing system.